# Integrating geolocated Twitter posts in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, import, twitter

Is it possible to integrate the lat/long data included with Twitter posts (those few that have it enabled of course) into an ArcGIS Desktop environment?

I've seen Twitter applications on ArcGIS Online that allow the position of Twitter posts on a base map.

I've also seen interesting mapart using Twitter geolocated twitter posts.  How is this done?

Keep in mind that we're looking to integrate these into a Desktop environment, not a Online environment.

Comment: Twitter API - https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1 (Geo & Places)

Comment: Do you want to add the real-time Twitter feed to your desktop map, or a snapshot of the Twitter data as of the time you captured/imported it? I imagine the mapart you reference is using a snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses!  Snapshot data would be fine, although it might be interesting to make it real time.  I agree that the twitter API's noted above are the way to access the data we're looking for.  The next step would be to get ArcGis to search the xml and select out the lat long data (i think this is called parsing?).I'll look into this on my end but I am open to reading other people's experiences with extracting lat long data from xml files.  Thanks again.

Comment: Where you mention arc map parsing, an excellent tool to accomplish is FME safe software.

Comment: I am a complete beginner with ArcGIS but I too have been looking for a way to live feed tweets to ArcGIS desktop. A quick google search brings this blogpost up from 2009: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2009/12/15/arcgis-explorer-and-geo-service-integration-twitter-add-in/ However, the link to the add-on is dead. Does this add-on still exist? If so, does anyone know where. If not, does anyone know why?

Answer (score 4):

When you view the details of the arcgis online app, if you select the Open button, you should get the choice to open in desktop.

[image: Twitter]

Comment: I guess all that does is pull in the basemap. I wonder why it is enabled.

Comment: Thanks for all your responses!  This wa my first post here and it seems quite fruitful.